# I want the overflow of a specified text to be transferred into another <p></p> tag

Tags: php, html, css, tags, overflow

I have made a web page with a card that, on click, flips around and reveals more content to review but, now I want that instead of specifying the text on the back side I can just transfer the overflow to behind the card. Is it possible? If not can you suggest any way arounds in php or css or html. Here is the link from where I got the idea to make the card. [Ammozon](http://ammozon.co.in/)

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] and [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

If what you are talking about is the code to how it works click on  Run code snippet to see it in action

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.recent__wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.recent__card {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 425px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.recent__card__inner {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgb(3, 0, 62);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(58deg, rgba(3, 0, 62, 1) 0%, rgba(117, 32, 124, 1) 50%, rgba(145, 237, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(58deg, rgba(3, 0, 62, 1) 0%, rgba(117, 32, 124, 1) 50%, rgba(145, 237, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(58deg, rgba(3, 0, 62, 1) 0%, rgba(117, 32, 124, 1) 50%, rgba(145, 237, 255, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#03003e", endColorstr="#91edff", GradientType=1);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.recent__card h2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.recent__card p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.recent__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.recent__card:hover .recent__card__inner {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.recent__card__front,
.recent__card__back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.recent__card__front {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    word-wrap: normal;
}

.recent__card__back {
    background-color: rgba(30, 143, 255, 0);
    color: white;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    word-wrap: normal;
}

.recent__btn a {
    text-decoration: #a6ffcb;
}

.recent__card button {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #131313;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="recent__wrapper">
    
<div class="recent__card">
        <div class="recent__card__inner">
          <div class="recent__card__front">
            <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing </p>
            <!--use exactly 420 Characters -->
          </div>
          <div class="recent__card__back">
            <p>
              when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only

 five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing.
            </p>
            <div class="recent__btn"><a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```